# Devforce code-first with Mysql

Tags: mysql, code-first, devforce

I have been trying to experiment Devforce code-first with MySql. But am not able to find any resources explaining how to do it. Even am not able to find whether DevForce code-first supports MySql or not. (EF supports). Please help!

Thanks,

Kannan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DevForce is generally ignorant about the underlying database provider, and doesn't have any special requirements to work with MySQL.  If you follow [DevForce documentation for working with Code First](http://drc.ideablade.com/devforce-2012/bin/view/Documentation/code-first), along with [MySQL documentation for working with EF](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html), you should be on the right track.  If you're using a paid version of DevForce, contact support directly to get more information if you run into problems.